# Running command via ssh while reading from a file ends the file reading

Tags: bash, shell

I have, very generally speaking, a bash script that reads some configuration data from a CSV file and performs an rsync backup.

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS="," read -r share source type subdir rsyncPath
do
  # Run preflight script for share
  [ -f "$share.preflight" ] && $share.preflight

  # Now run some rsync command to backup the data
done < <(grep -P -v '^\s*#' "inputfile")
```

The *inputfile* consists of lines like this:

```
Info,user@remotehost:/share,,,/usr/bin/sudo /opt/bin/rsync
docker,user@remotehost:/share,,,/usr/bin/sudo /opt/bin/rsync
```

There are additional preflight scripts present:

docker.preflight:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh user@remotehost 'echo Stopping docker service'
```

Info.preflight:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello Info.preflight"
```

In this example, the script reads both lines from the *inputfile* and performs each preflight script:

```
+ IFS=,
+ read -r share source type subdir rsyncPath
++ grep -P -v '^\s*#' shares
+ '[' -f ./Info.preflight ']'
+ ./Info.preflight
Hello Info.preflight
+ IFS=,
+ read -r share source type subdir rsyncPath
+ '[' -f ./docker.preflight ']'
+ ./docker.preflight
Stopping docker service
+ IFS=,
+ read -r share source type subdir rsyncPath
+ echo Done.
Done.
```

But if I switch the order and put the *docker* line first, the *docker.preflight* script is run and then the read loop ends, even though there is more input to consume.

```
+ IFS=,
+ read -r share source type subdir rsyncPath
++ grep -P -v '^\s*#' ./inputfile
+ '[' -f ./docker.preflight ']'
+ ./docker.preflight
Stopping docker service
+ IFS=,
+ read -r share source type subdir rsyncPath
+ echo Done.
Done.
```

Can anyone shed a light on what is going on here? How does runnign *ssh* interfere with my *read* loop?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089

Comment: Thanks @Jetchisel. I could have saved a lot of time by just putting the right words into the Google ;-)

Comment: There also a lot of entries for that, here and unix stack exchange.